# Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\dddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php) in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I have file attachment form in My laravel app. in this form I am going to save project_id to the file table also.

this is My form.blade.php

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=" {{route('projects.files', ['taskId'=>$task->id])}}"> // this is line 41
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my FileController methods is this

```
private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId)
{
    $file = new File;
    $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
    $file->project_id = $id;
    $file->task_id = $taskId;
    $file->save();
}
```

and routes

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/files', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but when I am going to submit file attach buttons it is generated following errors

```
ErrorException in 88ff5154a46f749c29024e0c9f84c577f7c5025e.php line 41: Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\John\Desktop\dddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: No any idea.....

Comment: I need some help to solve this problem?

Comment: What help do you need? The error message is very descriptive: you are trying to refer to the variable `$task` that doesn't exists in your view.

Comment: actually I tryed with so many ways.. but not successfull. can you guide me how can pass $task to the form action

Comment: It's laravel basics and I think you can learn it yoursef. Try this lessons https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch